# Numpy: Pandas nested condition in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

**Introduction**:
I have a pandas dataframe columns `df = [openDate, high, low, open, close, volume, is_eligible]` In which:

- openDate is date time type,
- high, low, open, close, volume is of int64type
- is_eligible boolean type

**Problem statement:** I want to add one more column `end_date` which will be calculated based on below:

if `is_eligible` is `true` then its `end_time` will be that closest`openDate` which row has `high` value `>=` that of the `is_eligible true`

**Example:** Let say row no 3 has `is_eligible == true , high=20, low=10, open=15, close=12` then we have to find out next immediate row which has the `high` value `>=` `20`.

**My approach:** I tried the following solution vectorised approach but not working.

```
temp_var = df[["openDate","is_eligible","high"]].copy()
df["end_date"] = np.where(
 temp_var['is_eligible'] == True,
 np.where(
  df['high']> temp_var["high"],
  df["openDate"],
  datetime.now()
 ),
 datetime.now()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have another approach:

```py
#Sort data with openDate column to make sure that the next openDate is the closest one
#Make sure that openDate in a timedate format
df.sort_values(['openDate'])

#Initiate the new column with NULL values
df['end_time'] = np.nan

#Now we will go throw the indexes of eligible rows which is sorted
list_of_indexes = list(df[df['is_eligible'] == True].index)

for i in range(len(list_of_indexes) - 1):
    
    #For each row I find the next one which match the criteria
    for j in range(i + 1, len(list_of_indexes)):
        
        if df['high'][j] >= df['high'][i]:
            #once I find it, I assign the value to my new column and break the inner loop
            df['end_time'][i] = df['openDate'][j]
            break
```

Comment: Ya, but I wanted to do it with vectorisation because I have huge amount of data which will  take time with normal loops. But thanks for your reply.